# Running server and client python scripts from a single python script or GUI button

Tags: python, sockets

I have been working with python server and client communication. In order to establish a connection, usually, the server needs to run 1st and then client from separate python scripts.

What I want now is to make it automated. I want to run both server and client from a single python script or a GUI button. I have been trying different ways like multiprocessing and multithreading but it is not working.

Please advice.

Sample server and client codes below:

**Server.py**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5005))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print("received data",list(data))
    if not data:
        break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('0.0.0.0', 5005))
message = bytearray([1])
s.sendall(message)
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print ('Received', repr(data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can handle it by assigning two different functions. A few notes:

- When two different threads are trying to print something in a same stream, they should acquire a common lock first so that they print something in order.
- Server starts listening on `"0.0.0.0"` means it is ready to accept a connection from anywhere. On the other hand, when you're running the client side on your machine, you should connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of connecting to `0.0.0.0`.

```py
import threading
import socket

stream_lock = threading.Lock()

def server_func():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5005))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        # Getting printing stream lock is important
        stream_lock.acquire()
        print("received data", list(data))
        stream_lock.release()
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data)
    conn.close()

def client_func():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5005))
    message = bytearray([1, 2, 3])
    s.sendall(message)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    stream_lock.acquire()
    print('Received', repr(data))
    stream_lock.release()

t_server = threading.Thread(target=server_func).start()
t_client = threading.Thread(target=client_func).start()

# Output:
# received data [1, 2, 3]
# Received b'\x01\x02\x03'
```

Answer (score 1):

i convert @aminrd 's answer to class object and add some code to store received data from client also added some comments for who need to understand each step

```
import socket
import threading
import json
import time


class Communication:
    stream_lock = threading.Lock()  # creating thread lock object

    def __init__(self):
        self.clientSocket = None
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # create socket and store
        self.STORED_DATA = {"function_name": "", "data": ""}  # sample stored data
        self.th = []  # threads list

    def server(self):
        self.serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,
                                     1)  # make reusing adress with different port
        self.serverSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5005))  # bind socket with port
        self.serverSocket.listen(2)  # permitted client number
        print("Server is listening")
        while True:
            client, address = self.serverSocket.accept()  # welcome new client
            # send client data to new thread and process
            self.th.append(threading.Thread(target=self.listener, daemon=True, args=(client,)).start())

    def listener(self, client):
        while True:
            data = client.recv(2048)  # receive new data to store
            if data:
                # you can get data from any client and puch data to all clients(multiple status monitors)
                data_variable = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))  # decode byte to dict
                self.stream_lock.acquire()  # i'm not sure about usage of lock. wrong place ?
                if 'command' in data_variable and data_variable['command'] == 'write':
                    self.STORED_DATA = data_variable
                else:
                    # or you can do some server stuff and manipulate data
                    self.STORED_DATA['function_name'] = 1
                    self.STORED_DATA['data'] = 1
                self.stream_lock.release()
                data_string = json.dumps(self.STORED_DATA).encode('utf-8')  # convert stored data to bytes
                client.sendall(data_string)  # now send stored data to all clients

    def client(self):
        self.clientSocket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5005))  # connect to server

    # this function is callable from outside of class
    # you can give new data to client to send to server
    def receive(self, new_data_string):
        self.clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # create socket for client
        self.clientSocket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5005))  # connect to server
        data_string = json.dumps(new_data_string).encode('utf-8')  # convert data to bytes
        self.clientSocket.send(data_string)  # send to server
        data = self.clientSocket.recv(2048)  # receive server data
        if not data:
            print("no data")
            self.clientSocket.close()
        data_variable = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))  # convert data to dict
        self.stream_lock.acquire()
        self.stream_lock.release()
        self.clientSocket.close()
        return data_variable  # return received data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Communication()
    t_server = threading.Thread(target=x.server, daemon=True).start()
    read = {"command": "read", "function_name": "", "data": ""}
    result = x.receive(read)
    print('Client Received', repr(result))
    time.sleep(1)
    write = {"command": "write", "function_name": "2", "data": "2"}
    result = x.receive(write)
    print('Client Received', repr(result))
```

Comment: as non coder person i'm proud with myself.solved this problem just with help of stackoverflow and some goole search.now i can focus developing small pygame project :)